# How to get unique column value and get the first entry and last entry from a cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have the following Sqlite table:

```
Name            Date
Challen         2016-03-04
Challen         2016-03-12
Challen         2016-05-14
Challen         2016-02-20
Testing         2016-07-14
Testing         2016-08-22
Testing         2016-07-29
Testing         2016-09-12
```

I have a class which gets those data and in my activity I am retriving them in a Cusor:

```
Cursor crs = MyDBHelper.GetTheData(); // retrieves all the rows above
PopulateLV pgv = new PopulateLV(getActivity(), crs);
...
public class PopulateLV extends CursorAdapter {
    public PopulateLV(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.disp_data_in_grid, parent, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        //question...
    }
}
```

ListView single item template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/start" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/end" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I am looking to do is:

- Get unique `Name` column from the table and populate a textview in a listview
- From the unique name above, (ordered by `Date`) get the first `Date` entry (which is the first row) and the last `Date` entry (which is the last low

The end ListView should look like this:

```
Challen
Start: 2016-02-20
End: 2016-05-14
-----------------------------------------
Testing
Start: 2016-07-14
End: 2016-09-12
-----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you retrieving all the data into the `cursor`? From your question it doesn't look like you need to load everything from the database and then filter it. Instead you should just write a meaningful SQL query and only retrieve the things you need.

```
SELECT name, MIN(date) AS start, MAX(date) AS end
FROM some_table
GROUP BY name
```

This gives me the following result:

```
name        start           end

Challen     2016-02-20      2016-05-14
Testing     2016-07-14      2016-09-12
```

Comment: I see what you are saying... I am going to test it out. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it did. `CursorAdapter` works with a cursor, which holds a result of a query. You just need to know how it works and write the right query ;)

Comment: I thought Sqlite works differently than Sql... I guess not :)